# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, jquery

im getting this weird message its really awful. Here you can see a fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/8/

Or you can paste the next code into an html ,

if is it a syntax mistake why it dosent tell me the line where the error is??

Also every time i clic next (When the overlay is open) the error comes again so after 5 clics, i have 5 errors on console.

Thanks

```
 <div id="navpics"><a href="javascript:();" class="prevImg">NEXT</a><div id="imageCounter"></div><a href="javascript:();" class="nextImg">PREV</a></div>
```

Comment: xhtml transitional?  What year is this?

Comment: That's a huge chunk of code which nobody is gonna read. Where exaclty are you experiencing the syntax error?

Comment: well a side note: the `api.next();  ` is outside the script block...

Comment: Well, `<a href="javascript:();">` is definitely a javascript syntax error. What did you intend with that?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome v. 27. The only error I got in the console was one about an image `blank.gif` that could not be found ***404 Not Found***. Which part is not working and what browser is it now working in?...

Comment: And what is `current` for?

Comment: If i get rid of the javascript:(); it wont work, why? thats a good question.. i dont know

Comment: current is set for the current image , as they are changing as you clic

Comment: @Jules: *What* does not work then?

Comment: api.next();  (out of box) o yes , im sorry forget to delete that, but that dosent send error, thats just print api.next(); ... SO thats not the cause of the error in chrome console

Comment: @Bergi .. in this example works everything (or it seems) but of you open the overlay (maximize image & clic next it works) but you will see error on console, i just have an error syntax, where i dont know, but when i insert this code in this script http://queretaro.orsilin.com.mx/index.php?page=item/view/15/Probando i got other errors, tried disabling al script less this one, and its not working, so I thought the first step was to check if this syntas is ok, and i found a mistake on chrome console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:();" class="nextImg">NEXT</a>
```

It does not like the ();

If you insist on using the anchor like that use [`void(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nextImg">NEXT</a>
```